# jboss modules system dependencies from ear/lib

Tags: jar, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-modules

I am trying to add more functionality to a product i work on( it is web application) by using jboss modules, the product is a .ear file which contains a utility.jar (this jar is inside the lib folder inside .ear file). Now I am trying to add a single class file by using jboss modules, i have created a jar which contains the new class file and i am trying to add the dependency in module.xml since this new class needs lot of files/class from utility.jar's different packages (around 15 classes are used/imported to compile this new class). Is it possible to achieve this.

I am trying to do this way since product team is the owner for deployment and they don't want to touch/modify the .ear file,hence i can't ask them to just add the new class file in the utility.jar (which works perfectly by the way). 
            Content of the module.xml are given below.

*Error message in jboss log is 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xyx.mdm.wkflw.eng.activities.SqActInstImpl from [Module "com.xyx.mdm:main" from local module loader @5add5415 (roots: D:\project\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules)]*

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.xyx.mdm">
<resources><resource-root path="activity.jar" />
</resources>
<dependencies>
<system export="true">
            <paths>               
                <path name="com/xyx/mdm/wkflw/eng/activities"/>
            </paths>
        </system>
</dependencies>
</module>
```

Comment: Let me see if I understand. You have deployed an ear, with an utility.jar inside, that have multiple classes in different packages. And you are trying to compile a class that have dependencies with the classes inside utility.jar. How are you packaging and deploying this new class? Are you installing this new class inside a module, right? If that is the case, you are having problems adding a dependency between this new module, and the jar inside the ear, right?

Comment: @AlejandroGoñi You got everything right ,some points for clarification, How are you packaging and deploying this new class? I am creating this class from java file in eclipse in a project where I have to add utility.jar file since dependency is there.Then I jar/zip this class with correct package hierarchy com.xyx...... into activity.jar. Then I install it as module using the module.xml given above.And yes dependency issue crops up saying class from the ear/lib's utility jar not found, Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ....from [Module "com.xyx.mdm:main" from local module loader

Comment: were you able to resolve this @saket?

Comment: @Sampada nope,after reading documents and links you/others shared I conclude that its not possible to implement my requirement .